# Powershell tab-complete trailing slash

Tags: powershell

In Powershell, when you are typing in a path, using tab-completion, directories don't get a trailing (back)slash, meaning that at each level, I have to type Tab - . Is there any way to make Powershell add the trailing backslash to directories it has autocompleted, like Bash does?

Answer (score 3):

[PowerTab](http://powertab.codeplex.com/) is an extension which adds Intellisense-like capabilities to Powershell. You may find that you like the way its pop-up lists and use of backslash and space to select completions works. It doesn't solve the problem of no trailing backslash, but the author says that the issue is with the [way Powershell works](http://www.techtalkz.com/microsoft-windows-powershell/508111-getting-rid-cmd-host.html#post2035421).

[PowerTab Cheat Sheet](http://cid-773dd79077a6cdde.office.live.com/view.aspx/.Public/PowerTab/PowerTab%20Cheat%20Sheet.doc)

Comment: I tried using it before asking this question, but I couldn't figure out how to install it, and the docs are completely lacking. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: @tghw: Yeah, the docs are pretty bad. Unzip the file into `Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` so you have a new directory under that called `PowerTab`. Then in PS do `Import-Module powertab`. See [this](http://thepowershellguy.com/blogs/posh/archive/2010/08/06/discovering-powertab-v2-series-part-1-installation-or-upgrade-from-v1.aspx) for further instructions. You will get error messages (and will need to/unless you) manually [create a directory and some files](http://thepowershellguy.com/blogs/posh/pages/powertab.aspx#16436).

Comment: PowerTab will not add trailing backslashes to a directory, but it does support recursive tab expansion based on typing a backslash.  The reason for this is that it would break chaining of tab expansion.  PowerShell will only call a new TabExpansion() if the command line has changed since the last TabExpansion().  So adding a backslash to the result would mean that you could not press <TAB> again.

Answer (score 1):

On the off-chance that someone stumbles over this in 2018:

[PSReadLine](https://github.com/lukesampson/pshazz/wiki/Prompt-variables) is a neat module that does this and much more. Installing it is as simple as running 2 commands (In PS5 - for older versions, check the README):

```
Install-Module PSReadLine
Import-Module PSReadLine
```

With a little configuration, PSReadline can do much more advanced things, but Tab-Autocompletion, proper Ctrl-C/Ctrl-V and some other things work out of the box.

Windows 10 includes PSReadLine by default.